# Shopify Graphql code returning Error 404. Also noticed that it works on .myshopify domain but not on custom

Tags: api, graphql, shopify, graphql-js, shopify-app

I do have a question regarding Graphql, i made it work but when we changed our domain from ".myshopify" to "custom" domain, it stopped working, it returns a error 400.

Here's the complete error.

OPTIONS https://testwebsite.myshopify.com/admin/api/graphql.json 400

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://testwebsite.myshopify.com/admin/api/graphql.json' from origin 'https://testwebsite.com.au' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Hope you can give me an answer.

Thank you

Comment: The proper way to target it is `https://testwebsite.myshopify.com/api/2019-10/graphql.json` There shouldn't be any admin. And I don't know if you are using Storefront API or GraphQL Admin.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer, i am using GraphQL Admin. Also, any suggestion why i am having an error 429 Too Many Request :(

Comment: Because there is a bucket limit of 1000. You can read on it here: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/graphql-admin-api-rate-limits The Admin GraphQL requires an Access Token, are you using one?

Comment: GraphQL does not return 429 in and of itself. Getting that means you're doing something really wrong!

Comment: Hi drip, Yes i have access token.

@David - can you please explain more?